# How to open magnet links from firefox with deluge

Tags: firefox, bittorrent, deluge

How can I open magnet links with firefox? I tried setting following values in about:config,

```
network.protocol-handler.app.magnet -> /usr/bin/deluge
network.protocol-handler.expose.magnet -> true
network.protocol-handler.external.magnet -> true
```

But firefox keeps on complaining about

> Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (magnet) isn't associated with any program.

I am using repository version of firefox (5) and deluge (1.3.1 - gui+daemon mode) on ubuntu 11.04

Edit: I was told to set `network.protocol-handler.expose.magnet` to false and firefox would ask which application to use, but I see no box asking me something appearing.

Comment: @Eyal  Good idea.  I've flagged this question for merging with one of the dupes.  This will move all answers over.

Comment: is this current?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

as of firefox 3.6 `network.protocol-handler.external.*` seems to no longer work

in `about:config`

```
network.protocol-handler.expose.magnet -> false
```

and 'reset' all other values to do with magnet.

once you click a magnet link you will be prompted to choose an application, navigate to and select /usr/bin/deluge

You might also try

```
$ gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/command 'deluge "%s"'
$ gconftool-2 -t bool -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/needs_terminal false
$ gconftool-2 -t bool -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/enabled true
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this (including the reset) but it didn't ask anything. The thing is this worked with Transmission (default app), but after I uninstalled transmission I can't get it to point to deluge in any way.

Comment: Strange, worked for me. I've added the steps for changing gnome's default url handling, dont think firefox takes any notice of it but its worth a try.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll try it again as soon as I get home.

Comment: the other thing to check is in firefox's preferences under applications, if there is already an entry for magnet.

Comment: Well, selecting "use..." there and manually going to `/usr/bin/deluge` did the trick, thank you :)!

Answer (score 5):

In Firefox go to Edit/Preferences/Applications, search magnet and set Deluge

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Instead of clicking on the magnet link in Firefox (which requires some advanced configuration to set up), right-click on the link and select "Copy Link Location".  Then, move into your Deluge window, click Add Torrent (the "+" at the top-left of the window), and then click the "URL" button.

Happy torrenting, and remember to go for a 3:1 seed ratio!

Comment: Well, it's not really that advanced, but that can be solved with a quick google search (I would tell you if I actually remembered how, I'm kind of a noob too).

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a solution to the problem as stated, but it's good to note it, yes :)

Answer (score 2):

was trying to get magnets to open with deluge in chrome rather than firefox but after trying everything else i had seen i finally managed to make magnet links open in deluge by not only changing

```
MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;
```

to

```
MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;x-scheme-handler/magnet;
```

in /usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop but also removing

```
x-scheme-handler/magnet;
```

from /usr/share/applications/transmission-gtk.desktop before running

```
sudo update-desktop-database
```

hope this helps anyone with similar problems

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually installed deluge? If not, open a terminal and enter this command. `sudo apt-get install deluge` When its done it should show up in the programs list.

Comment: I think that the problem is he doesn't know how to get it to link with firefox (e.g. he clicks a magnet link and then firefox wants to know what to open it with and asks him to browse to the executable).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, FF 47, Debian 9, KDE 5:

1. In about:config find "network.protocol-handler.expose-all", change to "false";
2. Click on some magnet link - a file browser pop-up should appear, show it full path to the executable (/usr/bin/qbittorrent for ex.);
3. Change "network.protocol-handler.expose-all" back to "true";
4. Download the world.

Comment: thanks, this is the only solution that worked for me, so weird

Answer (score 0):

The `deluge.desktop` file that's installed (in `/usr/share/applications` or similar) by the `deluge` package should already contain the

```
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/magnet
```

line that associates `deluge` with magnet links. However, in my case I found that for the system to pick up this association, I had to run:

```
sudo update-desktop-database
```

If this command is not found, the package `desktop-file-utils` needs to be installed first.