# How do i download a torrent in deluge?

Tags: downloads, bittorrent, deluge

I am trying to download a torrent. I try to navigate to the magnet link, but my web browser asks me what program the link should open with.  I tried to find browse to deluge in the window, but it's no there!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/53102/47206, http://askubuntu.com/q/108925/47206

Comment: This question has the best answer (by @cipricus) but [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53102/how-to-open-magnet-links-from-firefox-with-deluge) is older. They should be combined with the useful answer below.