# How do I download a torrent file from PirateBay?

Tags: bittorrent

When I try to download a torrent file I don't get prompted by Ubuntu 12.04 to select the location where to save the file, instead I get asked to select an application (which I'm not able to select for whatever reason). If anyone could help out with this it would be greatly appreciated. Please note that I've installed Ubuntu two days ago and I'm completely new to the thing.
Explain as if you were talking to a 5 years old kid. Or a golden retriever. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: My bad, I wasn't trying to download a torrent file, I was trying to use a magnet-link

Comment: either close the question , or select any working answer for future reference , if any solved your question..

Comment: either http://askubuntu.com/questions/44849/how-to-configure-chrome-to-open-magnet-urls-with-deluge or http://askubuntu.com/questions/53102/how-to-open-magnet-links-from-firefox-with-deluge

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu comes with preinstalled  `transmission`.

Open dash and search for transmission BitTorrent client , click on it and just drag the torrent link to the bit torrent. It will ask you where to download , provide the path . thats it.

Here is the screen short of [image: Transmission Bit Torrent Client] .

Advice : I use qBittorrent instead of transmission.

[image: qBittorrent]

For installing qBittorrent ,preferred method  go to ubuntu-software-center and search for qbittorrent and click install or use

```
sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

and provide your password. hope it helped you.

Comment: I have 12.04 and transmission wasn't preinstalled. Is this feature only on newer versions?

Comment: the better option is qBittorrent , open Ubuntu-Software center and search for it , install it .. and drag the link into it.

Comment: Why is qBittorrent better?  I don't use torrents often but have not noticed any issues with Transmission?  Just curious for my info, not a criticism...

Comment: see the thing is its your personal choice, for me i have used delug the most because of the fact that its fast among all ,but for that you need to add repository secondly the option transmission i mentioned because its installed in ubuntu by default , finally qbittorrent because it runs and provides the same features on all major platforms including Linux, Mac OS X and Windows, and my friends with mac and windows are using it too , thats why i use this , and it is also available in Ubuntu repositories by default.

Comment: Yes, qBittorent is the best!

Answer (score 2):

You could try installing [qBittorrent](http://www.qbittorrent.org/). It has a nice, easy to understand and use GUI.
To install qBittorrent press `Ctrl + Alt + T` or tap the *super key* (i.e. *windows button* in *Windows OS*) and type *terminal* and click the *Terminal icon* that appears in the dash.

In the terminal, enter the following command to install qBittorrent:

```
sudo apt-get install -s qbittorrent
```

To start qBittorrent, tap the *super key* and type qBittorrent and click its icon in dash. 
[image: dash menu]

You can download the .torrent file and open it with the application or add the magnetic link to the torrent, and download the way you want.
[image: magnetic link, qBittorrent]