# How to open magnet torrent links from Firefox in rTorrent?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, scripts, firefox, rtorrent

I am using the command-line torrent client [rTorrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTorrent) under Xenial Xerus and I would like to:

1. Find and click on a [magnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme) torrent link with Firefox
2. Have the magnet link opened automatically in rTorrent and start downloading

I believe a script is needed to be called from within Firefox, but the writing of such a script has so far defeated me...

Comment: Indeed this is what I am doing at the moment but I am after a more automated approach...

Comment: Check https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1012864

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problems usually lie with mime type and default handlers.

Firstly, have you changed Firefox's `about:config` settings? ie:

```
network.protocol-handler.expose.magnet -> false
```

and reset other options 
[as per this Firefox deluge Q&A.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53102/how-to-open-magnet-links-from-firefox-with-deluge?rq=1)

Have you set up rTorrent to watch any particular directory?

***FILE: ~/.rtorrent.rc***

```
# Maximum and minimum number of peers to connect to per torrent.
min_peers = 50
max_peers = 80

# Maximum number of simultanious uploads per torrent.
max_uploads = 5

# Global upload and download rate in KiB. "0" for unlimited.
download_rate = 0
upload_rate = 50

# Default directory to save the downloaded torrents.
directory = $HOME/torrents/downloads

# Watch a directory for new torrents
# SET your watch directory here --v 
schedule = watch_directory,5,5,$HOME/torrents/watch/*.torrent

port_range = 60125-64125
port_random = yes
dht = auto

# UDP port to use for DHT.
dht_port = 63425

# Enable peer exchange (for torrents not marked private)
peer_exchange = yes

# Check hash for finished torrents.
check_hash = yes

encryption = allow_incoming,try_outgoing ,enable_retry
```

Then it is a simple matter of "save as" into `$HOME/torrents/watch`.

Change `$HOME/torrents/watch` to whatever torrents subfolder you use, or at least $HOME to /home/username

Create a file and add the following script:

***FILE: maglink-rtorrent.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $HOME/torrents/watch    # set your watch directory here
[[ "$1" =~ xt=urn:btih:([^&/]+) ]] || exit;
echo "d10:magnet-uri${#1}:${1}e" > "meta-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.torrent"
```

Don't forget to make it executable

```
chmod +x maglink-rtorrent.sh
```

This also offers the ability to download from terminal by:

```
cd $HOME/torrents/watch
./maglink-rtorrent.sh "MAGNET-LINK-HERE"
```

Further awesome [Service Tips and rTorrent setup options here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RTorrent).

Futher credits:

- [magnet links and command line 1](http://paxmontem.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/magnet-links-in-arch-linux-with.html)
- [magnet links and command line 2](http://snarvaez.com.ar/libertad/index.php/2013/05/10/download-magnet-links-with-rtorrent-from-command-line/)

### Update 2:

If not using rTorrent, but kTorrent or qBittorent, then this following is the way to get that running:

```
# check defaults
xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/magnet
gvfs-mime --query x-scheme-handler/magnet

# set defaults
xdg-mime default qBittorent.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet
gvfs-mime --set x-scheme-handler/magnet qBittorrent.desktop
```

There's a further setting (from memory) for whether you require commandline.

For rTorrent though, this link is the [FlexGet rTorrent Magnet URI Handler](http://flexget.com/Plugins/rtorrent_magnet)

[Full information here.](http://community.rutorrent.org/MagnetUri)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have managed to crack this one on my own using: http://paxmontem.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/magnet-links-in-arch-linux-with.html but I would be more than happy to award the bonus if you can bend your answer this way...

Comment: Ha! I was going to add that script to my answer, but chose not to for it being a terminal option - where I thought you were after a pure browser one-click option. [link](http://snarvaez.com.ar/libertad/index.php/2013/05/10/download-magnet-links-with-rtorrent-from-command-line/)

Comment: Not so much the terminal script on the bottom of your link. Looks like the Browser can be set to pass the magnet link to a script to clean it up and pass it to the rtorrent  watch directory. I used this page: http://paxmontem.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/magnet-links-in-arch-linux-with.html but it all feeds off the ARCH wiki page...

Answer (score 1):

The following script is a spin on [Max Gonzih's code](https://blog.gonzih.me/blog/2012/02/17/how-to-use-magnet-links-with-rtorrent/) that works both with regular .torrent files and magnet links:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

torrent_file_or_magnet_link="$1"

# Edit rtorrent.rc to automatically start downloads when a .torrent file
# appears in this directory.
cd "$HOME/.rtorrent/watch/start/"

# XT stands for "exact topic".
# BTIH is the BitTorrent info hash:
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme#BitTorrent_info_hash_(BTIH)
# This is the hex-encoded SHA-1 hash of the torrent file info section
magnet_regex="xt=urn:btih:([^&/]+)"
if [[ "$torrent_file_or_magnet_link" =~ $magnet_regex ]]; then
  torrent_hash=${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
  magnet_link_length=${#torrent_file_or_magnet_link}
  # To conform with the bencode encoding, the magnet link's number of characters
  # must be part of the torrent file, otherwise rTorrent can't read it.
  # Same for the "e" at the end.
  # See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode
  torrent_file_content="d10:magnet-uri${magnet_link_length}:${torrent_file_or_magnet_link}e"

  # Note that rTorrent will read this torrent file, start downloading
  # the file and then remove the torrent file
  echo "$torrent_file_content" > "$torrent_hash.torrent"
else
  cp "$torrent_file_or_magnet_link" .
fi
```

You can use this in a script (let's call it `pass_to_rtorrent.sh`) and have Firefox pass the torrent file or magnet link to the script:

[image: Firefox rTorrent screenshot]

Make sure the script is executable: `chmod +x pass_to_rtorrent.sh`