# Cannot find "/usr/bin/deluge" but can open Deluge Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, firefox, bittorrent, deluge

Hello and thanks ahead for reading.  I downloaded Deluge on my new Ubuntu 16.04 system running Firefox v48.0 .  I downloaded Deluge and can run it if I search for it using the launcher.

I'm trying to open a magnet torrent download link and am getting the "Launch Application" pop up saying:

> This link needs to be opened with an application.
>
> Send to:

and I see

> Transmission

as my highlighted option and with

> Choose an Application__________[Choose...]

I cannot find any appropriate Deluge program in my directories when I click the "Choose" button.  I also checked "/myUser/bin/" for it and there is no "deluge" in it as per:

[How to open magnet links from firefox with deluge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53102/how-to-open-magnet-links-from-firefox-with-deluge)

Can I either find the correct program file to select when this option occurs or preset the default on my system to always launch Deluge every time I click a download link?

Thanks again ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing that:

In a terminal, enter

> ```
>  which deluge
> ```

That should show you the path to the executable that would be used to open deluge from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to help you find the right executable:

```
sudo find / -iname \*deluge\*
```

Then you should be able to find the correct executable from the "Choose" box.